# How to detect two consecutive taps on a row in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uigesturerecognizer

in my app I want the user to tap twice on a row to display an alert view to show detail information from the selected row. At the moment I have implemented two other gestures, swipe from left to right and long-press for 1 sec.
Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
  }

    //long press gesture
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.00;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
    //end of long press gesture11111
    //swipe left-right
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGestureLeftRight:)];
    [swipeLeftRight setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRight];
    //end of swipe left-right


  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}
```

I haven't found anything about this that could be applied to my code, so that any proposal will be appreciated.

Comment: Add another gesturerecognizer (UITapGestureRecognizer) and set the `numberOfTaps` to two.  You are also going to need to set the `requiresGestureRecognizerToFail` to your other gesture recognizers just in case.

Comment: Do you need the 2 taps to be in quick succession, or time duration between the taps is not a factor?

Comment: Thank you @n00bProgrammer, what I need is 2 taps to be in quick succession, also a doubletap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in three different ways (differing depending on desired effect and coding style).

The first way would be to add a doubletap gesture recognizer (if you are looking for double tap instead of two taps over any amount of time).  That I think you can code out yourself.

The second would be to detect cell selections:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Check if the cell at indexPath is currently the tableview's selected cell then you have double tap
}
```

The third is the same as the second, except you create an indexPath variable and set it in the `didselectrow` method.  Then if the next `didselectrow` call is the exact same indexPath then you have double tap.

My vote would be the saved variable.  I'm not certain how reliable the "selected" property of tableview's and cells are.  But you will have to implement the `didDeselectRow` function as well because that can get called in cases outside tableview selections.

Comment: Thank you again, to maintain the current code, I will try your first way. But a question before trying it, at the moment, as default, a single tap opens another view controller. If I add a double tap gesture recognizer, will it affect the default behaviour?

Comment: Yes it will.  You may have to add a singletap recognizer and a doubletap recognizer.  The singletap recognizer will have to have the doubletap as `recognizermustfail`.  That is the easiest way to deal with tapping/swiping things.  Apple's built in options are pretty robust for that.